# Return Error Code other than 403 from PolicyEvaluator when returning result of PolicyAuthorizationResult.Forbid()

Tags: c#, .net

Note this is dotnet core 3.1.  I am trying to return a status code of 451 from the PolicyEvaluator class code:

```
public override async Task<PolicyAuthorizationResult> AuthorizeAsync(
        AuthorizationPolicy policy,
        AuthenticateResult authenticationResult,
        HttpContext httpContext,
        object resource
    )
    {
        var result = await base.AuthorizeAsync(policy, authenticationResult, httpContext, resource);
        bool needsLegal = true;
        /*
            Check for Legal 
        */

        if (result.Succeeded && needsLegal)
        {
           result = PolicyAuthorizationResult.Forbid();
           httpContext.Response.StatusCode =
               StatusCodes.Status451UnavailableForLegalReasons;
        }  
        return result;
    }
```

but the status code aways ends up being '403'. Is there a way to return a status code other than '403'?

Comment: Looking at the code in the ASP.NET Core repo (https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/c925f99cddac0df90ed0bc4a07ecda6b054a0b02/src/Security/samples/CustomAuthorizationFailureResponse/Authorization/SampleAuthorizationMiddlewareResultHandler.cs#L22-L52), looks like you need to use a custom `IAuthorizationMiddlewareResultHandler` to change the response code.

Comment: Although that looks like it was added in 5.0.